# how to overcome performance issues when using virtual android device over RDP

Tags: android, amazon-ec2, android-virtual-device, rdp

I'm trying to develop for android on an android tablet.
So far the best option seems to be using an Amazon ec2 instance over RDP.

Eclipse works fine like this.

Only problem is that Android Virtual Devices display incredibly slowly over RDP.

The screen lock presents a challenge as click-hold-drag does not translate well.

Is there any workable alternative to executing the android executable?
Is there any way to speed up the AVD display?
Any way to disable the screen lock?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a direct answer, but an alternative approach:

On device development can be done using [TerminalIDE](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.spartacusrex.spartacuside).

On device development can be done using [AIDE](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.aide.ui).